PowerPages get the current authenticated contact in workflows process (PowerApps/Dynamics)
So I have a list of items. The idea is to have a workflow attached to that list that you can click on as an employee and be assigned to that item. The items Dataverse table have a contact look-up (employees are contacts as well). The idea is once you trigger the workflow, the item look-up to populate with the contact that triggered the workflow.
I found the following solution for such a remote thing but it does not seem to work: https://www.crmanswers.net/2013/10/get-current-user-inside-workflow.html
So on short, I want a workflow that is able to capture the currently authenticated contact GUID that triggers the as on-demand workflow (from PowerPages) and then put that GUID in the look-up.
Also I have tried this like an alternative from the url but I keep getting errors that it can't find the lookup provided (either it's not looking in the Contact table or it's something else):
using System;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

public class GetCurrentContact : CodeActivity
{
    [Output("Initiating Contact")]
    [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
    public OutArgument<EntityReference> InitiatingContact { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        IWorkflowContext workflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(workflowContext.UserId);

        if (workflowContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("No workflow context found.");
        }

        try
        {
            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("contactid"); 
            
            query.Criteria.AddCondition("emailaddress1", ConditionOperator.Equal, workflowContext.InitiatingUserId.ToString());

            EntityCollection contacts = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            if (contacts.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                EntityReference initiatingContactRef = contacts.Entities[0].ToEntityReference();
                InitiatingContact.Set(context, initiatingContactRef);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("No associated contact found for the initiating user.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = $"An error occurred in GetInitiatingContactId. Error: {ex.Message}";
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}


